# Seagate External Hard disk error

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, disk-space, hard-drive-recovery

Seagate Desktop external 1TB harddrive is having the following error:

"The request failed due to a fatal device hardware error."

I am able to view the folders but unable to open the files in the folders.

I am on Windows 10 operating system.

Comment: Presumably you wouldn't be asking if you could just swap out a new drive & restore from your backup... so, what have you tried so far & what were the results?

Comment: I connect the USB from the external hard disk to my computer and tried accessing the files. The error immediately came. How can I troubleshoot this problem? I have not backup the files in the external hard disk.

Comment: Error 0x800701E3: The request failed due to a fatal device hardware error.

Answer (score 0):

Seagate has some [tools for windows](http://www.seagate.com/files/www-content/support-content/downloads/seatools/_shared/downloads/SeaToolsforWindowsSetup.exe) that can be used to do a diagnostic of your drive.

I think it will provide you a code for a possible RMA, if the drive is sill under warranty.

Comment: The device is not under warranty.

Comment: Then this tool can probably be used to decide if you should still use this drive or not. I am personally very careful about losing data, I prefer spending some cash on a new drive than using a dubious drive.